# Running Docker Commands with a bash script inside a container

Tags: bash, ubuntu, deployment, docker

I'm trying to automate deployment with webhooks to the Docker hub based on [this tutorial](https://blog.rainforestqa.com/2015-01-15-docker-in-action-from-deployment-to-delivery-part-3-continuous-delivery/). One container runs the web app on port 80. On the same host I run another container that listens for post requests from the docker hub, triggering the host to update the webapp image. The post request triggers a bash script that looks like this:

```
echo pulling...
docker pull my_username/image
docker stop img
docker rm img
docker run --name img -d -p 80:80 my_username/image
```

A test payload succesfully triggers the script. However, the container logs the following complaints:

```
pulling...
app/deploy.sh: line 4: docker: command not found
...
app/deploy.sh: line 7: docker: command not found
```

It seems that the bash script does not access the host implicitly. How to proceed?

Stuff I tried but did not work:
when firing up the listener container I added the host IP like this based on the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/run/):

```
HOSTIP=`ip -4 addr show scope global dev eth0 | grep inet | awk '{print\$2}' | cut -d / -f 1`
docker run --name listener --add-host=docker:${HOSTIP} -e TOKEN="test654321" -d -p 5000:5000 mjhea0/docker-hook-listener
```

similarly, I substituted the --add-host command with `--add-host=dockerhost:$(ip route | awk '/docker0/ { print $NF }')` based on [this suggestion](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1143#issuecomment-70052272).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither the docker binary nor the docker socket will be present in a container by default (why would it?).

You can solve this fairly easily by mounting the binary and socket from the host when you start the container e.g:

```
$ docker run -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock debian docker --version
Docker version 1.7.0, build 0baf609
```

You seem to be a bit confused about how Docker works; I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "access the host implicitly" or how you think it would work. Think of a container as a isolated and ephemeral machine, completely separate from your host, something like a fast VM.

Comment: Excellent, this solves the issue!

My confusion rises from the fact that this is not mentioned in the tutorial which is otherwise very precise.